# Inserting python list into a mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to insert a python list into mongodb data. How would I insert it? 
Below is my code. The error is

> list has no method to_dict

Here is the code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.espace
espace = db.espacedata
records = a.to_dict(orient = 'records')
data = ['AGRICULTURE\n A01\nAGRICULTURE; FORESTRY; ANIMAL HUSBANDRY; HUNTING; TRAPPING; FISHING', ' A01\nAGRICULTURE; FORESTRY; ANIMAL HUSBANDRY; HUNTING; TRAPPING; FISHING', "FOODSTUFFS; TOBACCO\n A21\']
records = data.to_dict(orient = 'records')
results = espace.insert_many(records)
```

Comment: What does `a` stand for?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is `a` and where does it come from? Sounds like its a list and lists don't have a `to_dict` method.

Answer (score 0):

you could just use a dict that has as values your records, you could do:

```
espace.insert_many([{'records':data}]) 
# or
escape.insert_one({'records': data})
```

Answer (score 0):

First there is problem with syntax in `data`. It won't parse because of escaped quotes `\'` in the end. You need to add a closing single quote as given below.

```
data = ['AGRICULTURE\n A01\nAGRICULTURE; FORESTRY; ANIMAL HUSBANDRY; HUNTING; TRAPPING;
FISHING', ' A01\nAGRICULTURE; FORESTRY; ANIMAL HUSBANDRY; HUNTING; TRAPPING; FISHING',  
'FOODSTUFFS; TOBACCO\n A21\'']
```

In case if you are trying to use `pandas`, use following or as given above :

```
data = ['AGRICULTURE\n A01\nAGRICULTURE; FORESTRY; ANIMAL HUSBANDRY; HUNTING; TRAPPING; FISHING', ' A01\nAGRICULTURE; FORESTRY; ANIMAL HUSBANDRY; HUNTING; TRAPPING; FISHING', 'FOODSTUFFS; TOBACCO\n A21\'']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
records = df.to_dict()
print(records)
```

Otherwise as suggested by @rusu, use direct as :

```
espace.insert_many([{'records':data}])
```